# Comparing nvarchar with bigint in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, query-performance

I am investigating a performance issue for the following sql statement:

```
Update tableA 
set columnA1 = columnB1 
from tableB 
where tableA.columnA2 = tableB.columnB2
```

The problem is that `tableA.columnA2` is of type `nvarchar(50)` while `tableB.columnB2` is of type `bigint`. My question is how sql server execute such query; does it `cast bigint` to `nvarchar` and compare using `nvarchar` comparing operators or does it cast `nvarchar` to `bigint` and compare with `bigint` comparing operators.

Another thing: if I had to leave those column types as is `tableA.columnA2`, `tableB.columnB2`' how can I rewrite this query to enhance performance?

Note: this query is only working on around 100,000 records, but it takes like forever.

Thanks in advance, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

In the comparison, the `nvarchar` will be converted to `bigint`, because `bigint` has a higher precedence

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx

Comment: +1 It's surprising to me on how few developers know that the data type precedence exists. Even fewer understand the negative performance impact of matching on unlike types.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
I was assuming that the conversion is always to the data type of the updated table. But **this is wrong!** @podiluska's answer is correct, as I tested with a statement similar to that in the question, and in the plan for the update statement, you see that the conversion is always to bigint when you compare a bigint and a nvarchar column, no matter if the bigint or the nvarchar column is on the side of the updated table: The query plan always contains an expression `Scalar Operator(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,[schema1].[table1].[col1],0))` for the nvarchar column.

To help the performance, you can create a calculated column in the table B with the nvarchar column using the expression `cast(ColumnA2 as bigint)`. Then you could build an index on this and columnB1.

Comment: I would make the computed column in `tableA` with expression `cast(ColumnA2) as bigint)`. Usually is much cheaper to scan indexes when they are numeric.

Comment: Good point! But it might be that there are some nvarchars which are not numeric in the column in table A. You would at least have to take care in the expression for that.

Comment: @FranPl of course we could use `CASE ISNUMERIC...`; but it seems that  is not needed in this, since the original query didn't have such test, and didn't fail...  IMO it's a bad design.